# Why can't I load a simple CSV into Python 2.7 32 bit?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, machine-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0ukX.png)
[image]

I am reading an e-book on machine-learning by Dr. Joseph Brownlee.

This is the code from the book, and this is what I am getting. ( I do have the CSV. )

It may be my computer, because I haven't been able to load a CSV from any version of Python 3.

Comment: Never include code or anything else in a screenshot. Such things should be included in the question body and properly formatted. Please read [ask] and provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

### Why?

Josh, your `python`-interpreter is not using the same installation as Jason uses.

**First:** check, where is the Jason's CSV-file actually located ( python did not find it in his location )

**Next:** get that file moved/copied into your `python`-interpreter's directory.

**In case:** you may load the "classical" ML-dataset from [**here**](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/), just put it into the same directory, as your `python` is located and rename the file to match your `.csv` CSV-example

**If all fails:** ask Jason, where is the missing file, if it was some modified version of the "classic" ML-dataset.

<sub>Python 2.7 will make it. Do not panic. There is no need to worry about any Py3 remarks. Except for some printing issues to fix, the course will work for you in Py27 either.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the Python interpreter in the same folder as your csv file. Best way to do that would be write a Python script in the same folder, then just execute it

or give the full path to the file. `open(r"C:\Users\username\files\blah.csv")`

Also, you're using Python27, not Python3, and both will work, so it's recommended nowadays to use Python3

Comment: I am completely new. I have put the machine learning zipped bundle in my python folder, but that didn't help. I apologize, but I just don't understand. What you are asking. Could you share a  flow chart with picture examples?

Comment: You can't just "start the Python command prompt" from the start bar. It always will open in `C:\Python27`. You need to open a command prompt in the exact same folder as the file, and run `python` **or** write an actual `.py` file in the same folder, then you can run that